# python ModuleNotFoundError: import works from console but not from nested modules

Tags: python, import

I have a module called _local at the root of my project, and a file in another module that imports it:

[image]

when I run `python _devtools/test_import.py` from root folder, I get an error:

```
python _devtools/test_import.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_devtools/test_import.py", line 1, in <module>
    import _local
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_local'
```

when I try to import this module from the console, while staying in the same root folder, it works:

```
python
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5050, Mar 21 2017, 01:21:04)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import _local
>>>
```

What should I modify in my environment variables to make the import work?

Comment: Add the location of _local to the environment variable PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _local module is not visible from _devtools and cannot be accessed using relative imports since you are running the temp_import.py as the main script.

Here is simple hack using the sys.path modification,

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "../_local")
import _local
```